# DIO response decode issue

Tags: android, json, http, dart, flutter

I am using `Dio` for making the `HTTP` request

```
  var dio = Dio();
    var response =
        await dio.get(URL);
    final responseBody = json.decode(response.data);

    final statusCode = response.statusCode;

    if (statusCode != 200 || responseBody == null) {
      print("status code:$statusCode");
      throw new ServerExceptionHandler(
          "An error ocurred : [Status Code : $statusCode]", statusCode);
    }
```

> A response I am parsing

```
{
"x_id": "home"
}
```

but `json.decode(response.data)` is throwing the exception.

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

The Strange thing is when I replace `Dio` with `http.get(url)` then `json.decode(response.body)` works perfectly with same response

Comment: Look if [this](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/20) could help.

Comment: tried not working

Comment: Could you provide the url you are trying to get? Or at least could to get the json with postman e post it formatted on your question?

Comment: updated the JSON response

Comment: Okay got it. Wrote my answer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your response data is already a Map so you could simply do that:

```
var response = await dio.get(_url);
var responseBody = response.data;
print(responseBody);
```

This is with explicit types:

```
Response<Map> response = await dio.get(_url);
Map responseBody = response.data;
print(responseBody);
```

Comment: yes, it's working, DIO returns decoded MAP. not required to decode

Comment: @RahulDevanavar Yup. In this case (JSON body) it's so. For reference look at the [response.dart](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/flutter/lib/src/response.dart) repo code in toString. If you want you could also make this check too, but I guess that for a JSON body the response will always be a Map

Comment: i had very similar case and that really worked for me

Answer (score 5):

**Follow this approach**
Take the response as String. Now you can decode it...

```
 Response<String> response = await DioUtils.getInstance().get(JSON_API);
 List responseJson = json.decode(response.data);
 return responseJson.map((m) => new User.fromJson(m)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final dio = Dio(); 
    Response response = await dio.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception();
    } else {
      print("The response is that \n${response.data}\n"); 
       // no need to decode , when we use dio package , its response 
      // returns the String,dynamic
       return UserModel.fromMap(response.data); 
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to decode it. The dio package already decoded it from json to dart.